# Why is my calculation not appearing in this TextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, business-intelligence, finance

I am writing a simple program for fun on the Time Value of Money and am running into problems getting my variable calc posted into the calculateTF TextField.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

// The time value of money (TVM) is the idea that money available at the present time 
// is worth more than the same amount in the future due to its potential earning capacity.

// FV = Future value of money
// PV = Present value of money
// i = interest rate
// n = number of compounding periods per year
// t = number of years

// FV = PV x (1 + (i / n))^(n x t)

public class timeValue2 extends JFrame {

    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    private JLabel futureValue, presentValue, interestRate, periods, years, payment;
    private JTextField futureValueTF, presentValueTF, interestRateTF, periodsTF, yearsTF, paymentTF, calculateTF;
    private JButton calculateB, exitB;

    private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

    public timeValue2() {

        // Labels
        futureValue = new JLabel("Enter the future value: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        presentValue = new JLabel("Enter the present value: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        interestRate = new JLabel("Enter I/Y: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        periods = new JLabel("Enter periods: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        years = new JLabel("Enter years: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        payment = new JLabel("Enter payment: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        // Text Fields
        futureValueTF = new JTextField(10);
        presentValueTF = new JTextField(10);
        interestRateTF = new JTextField(10);
        periodsTF = new JTextField(10);
        yearsTF = new JTextField(10);
        paymentTF = new JTextField(10);
        calculateTF = new JTextField(10);

        // Buttons
        calculateB = new JButton("Calculate");
        cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
        calculateB.addActionListener(cbHandler);
        exitB = new JButton("Exit");
        ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
        exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

        setTitle("Time-Value of Money");

        Container pane = getContentPane();

        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        pane.add(futureValue);
        pane.add(futureValueTF);
        pane.add(presentValue);
        pane.add(presentValueTF);
        pane.add(interestRate);
        pane.add(interestRateTF);
        pane.add(payment);
        pane.add(paymentTF);
        pane.add(periods);
        pane.add(periodsTF);
        pane.add(years);
        pane.add(yearsTF);
        pane.add(calculateB);
        pane.add(calculateTF);
        pane.add(exitB);

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Here the .getText() operator gets the text from TF pane's. 

            double futureValue, presentValue, interestRate, periods, years, calc, payment;
            String fv, pv, ir, p, y, pmt;

            fv = futureValueTF.getText();
            pv = presentValueTF.getText();
            ir = interestRateTF.getText();
            p = periodsTF.getText();
            y = yearsTF.getText();
            pmt = paymentTF.getText();

            futureValue = Double.parseDouble(fv);
            presentValue = Double.parseDouble(pv);
            interestRate = Double.parseDouble(ir);
            periods = Double.parseDouble(p);
            years = Double.parseDouble(y);
            payment = Double.parseDouble(pmt);

            // Now I need to perform the TVM operations. 

            // What I need is a document listener

            if(fv.isEmpty()) {

                calc = presentValue * Math.pow((1 + (interestRate / years)), (years * periods));
                calculateTF.setText("" + calc);

            } else if(pv.isEmpty()) {

                calc = ((payment/interestRate) - futureValue) * (1/Math.pow((1 + interestRate), years)) - (payment / interestRate);
                calculateTF.setText("" + calc);

            } else if(ir.isEmpty()) {

                calc = (presentValue * Math.pow((1 + interestRate), years)) + (payment * ((Math.pow((1 + interestRate), years) - 1)/interestRate)) + futureValue;
                calculateTF.setText("" + calc);

            } else if(p.isEmpty()) {

                calc = (presentValue * Math.pow((1 + interestRate),periods)) + (payment * (((Math.pow((1 + interestRate),periods)) - 1)/interestRate)) + futureValue;
                calculateTF.setText("" + calc);

            } else if(pmt.isEmpty()) {

                calc = (presentValue + ((presentValue + futureValue)/(Math.pow((1 + interestRate),periods) - 1) * (-interestRate / 1)));
                calculateTF.setText("" + calc);

            } 

            // The .setText() operator sets the text in the (yet to be created) calculate box. 

        }

    }

    public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.exit(0);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        timeValue2 boss = new timeValue2();

    }

}
```

When ran, the code brings up the user interface and allows the user to input data but apparently either the calculations are not running or the value is not being placed within the TextField.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger. Which line isn't do what you expected?

Comment: Just getting: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Comment: I' m testing your code, debugging it, and I noticed that your `Calculate` button is not activated, so, I've inserted a lot of numbers, but my `breakpoint` is not called a single time.